# eclipse java heap space error, out of memory

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I have data file of 5 gb pcap file and i am doing preprocessing and converting it into csv file in windows 32 bit, java 32 bit eclipse java ee

it is showing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I have also tried increasing -Xmx1024m

is there any solution to solve java heap space errror

my system properites are 8GM ram and 500 gb harddisk

Comment: Does it run at all? or it crashes from the beginning

Comment: Are you trying to load in the entire file at once? If so , you should rather do it in chunks. Read a few lines / bytes at a time and process them before moving on to the next line/bytes. A 32-bit JVM can allocate maximum 4gb of ram , so loading the entire file won't work- even if you increase your XmX to that size.

Comment: I think you should post some code. Specially how you read the file

Comment: what if i use 64 bit JVM?